# How to get the primary key which is an auto-increment for the row just entered in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query like

```
$result = mssql_query("INSERT into CALLER
  ( status, media, media_2, first_name, last_name,  street_address, city,
  state, zipcode, home_phone_no, mobile_phone_no,email, problem, 
  medical_condition, comments,  updated_date )
  VALUES    
  ('CALL', '$media', '$media_2','$fname','$lname', '$street_addr', '$city',
  $state','$zip', '$phone_alt', '$phone','$email','$problem','$mc',
  '$comments',GetDate() ); ");
```

The `primary key for the table CALLER is an auto-increment`. How can I get the Primary Key of the row just inserted after this query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you have any [CANDIDATE KEY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key) in the table, you can use that to retrieve the last inserted row.

Say you have a candidate key consisting of columns `status`, `email` and `problem`.

Then you can execute a query like this just after your insert.

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM CALLER 
          WHERE 
               status = '" . $status . "' 
               AND email = '" . $email . "' AND 
               problem = '" . $problem . "'";
mssql_query($query);
```

This will return the id for that entry.

**Update**
I just saw this in a comment by Mikael to Femi's Answer, you can use [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

It returns the las insert id for the current connection in current scope. So it should work for you even if multiple instances do inserts which are interleaved.

So you can simply do this after the insert

```
$res = mssql_query('SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()');
```

Answer (score 4):

Correction: use this.

```
$query = mssql_query("SELECT @@IDENTITY");
$row   = mssql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Comment: Such insert queries can be simultaneously done my many clients. So getting the most recent PK wont work.

Say, I am userA and I was responsible for the insert query. Can I get the PK generated for the query I triggered?

Comment: As hight rep users, we should always teach to write readable code, that's why I replaced $q and $r with $query and $row. It's not just here, everywhere in the code where a variable appear later on, it will be more intuitive to read. like unset($query) or process($row)...

Comment: Also need to change the variable name in line 2: $q to $query.

Comment: You should really use `scope_identity()` instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx